# Does AWS Textract support Japanese as a language for OCR?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-textract

I am using AWS Textract to fetch data from forms that I am uploading to S3. I am unable to find any method to perform this on documents in Japanese.

Reading through the AWS Docs shows that there is no official support.

Are there any workarounds?

Comment: Please don't tag-spam - this question has nothing to do with Azure or GCP. Also, note that this is off-topic, as this isn't a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Reading through the AWS Docs shows that there is no official support.

Correct. Currently, as per [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/textract-best-practices.html#optimal-document), Amazon Textract only supports English, Spanish, German, Italian, French, and Portuguese.

It doesn't support Japanese.

> Are there any workarounds?

No, you need to use another OCR service that supports Japanese - either self-deployed, via the AWS Marketplace or another cloud provider.

A few self-deployed / AWS marketplace options could be [Tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract) or [NHocr](https://code.google.com/archive/p/nhocr/).

Alternative options available on other cloud providers, in no specific order:

- [Azure AI Vision with OCR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/computer-vision/overview-ocr), optimised via the [Document Intelligence read model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/document-intelligence/concept-read?view=doc-intel-3.1.0),  with full Japanese support for [handwritten](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/computer-vision/language-support#handwritten-text) & [print](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/computer-vision/language-support#print-text) text
- [Google Cloud Vision OCR](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr) with full Japanese support for [handwritten](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/languages#supported-langs) & [print](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/languages#supported-langs) text

I would personally recommend just trying out Azure & GCP for your Japanese OCR needs & checking their suitability against your requirements e.g. cost, compliance, quality, ease of use etc.

Comment: Any suggestion on what we can use ?

Comment: @codeforHarman I've updated my answer, does that help?

Comment: Yes it does, thanks a lot :)